# window.onload wont execute in wordpress

Tags: jquery, javascript

I have some code I am trying to execute on my [webpage](https://linestar.ca/contact-us/). At first I was trying to just using JS but now I am wrapping it in JQuery as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327085/jquery-ready-function-doesnt-work-in-wordpress). Code is loading in page but no alert is happening...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){

window.onload = function() {
alert(location.href);
if(location.href != "https://linestar.ca/contact-us/") {
      alert("Make sure you use the right contact Tab!");
} else {
    echo"LineStar Welcomes You!"
}

};


});
```

Comment: Your console is showing error, i also noticed that you are uinga cache plugin combining all your js file. Try to desactivate it and test again

Comment: On top of what @TemaniAfif said 1) you are including two versions of jQuery, and 2) using jQuery .ready() + window.onload is redundant - .ready() attaches to document DOMContentLoaded as well as window load events and may also fire long after both depending on when it is called.

Answer (score 3):

Well don't mix **PHP** and **Javascript** without the **proper tags**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){

        if(location.href != "https://linestar.ca/contact-us/") {
            alert("Make sure you use the right contact Tab!");
        } else {
            alert("LineStar Welcomes You!");
        }

    });
</script>
```

*As a sidenote, your website has lots of issues that you have to work out eventually.*